# Is it possible to create a user-dependent link to a network folder?

Tags: filesystems, network-shares, symbolic-link

This is, I guess, more of an academic question, but is it possible to create a link at common pointing to the user's network-home directory?
So, when user A follows this link, it points to Homedrive/userA, and when user B follows the link, it points to Homedrive/userB.

In my company, we have two network drives, Common and Homedrive. Common is accessible to all employees, whereas Homedrive contains for each user a network-home directory, which is only accessible for the user him- or herself.

- Common
- Homedrive

  - userA
  - userB

So user A can access Common as well as Homedrive/userA, whereas user B may only access Common and Homedrive/userB.

Comment: This question as it stands, is too broad. You need to at least specify the server and client operating systems.

Comment: I can not tell the operating system of the server, since I am just an ordinary employee. I guess the scenario I am asking about would most probably be possible in a Windows/Windows or Linux/Linux sitation.

Comment: You don't have to hang on links: once it comes to a somewhat common desktop, you are free to place an icon there which leads to a script that opens any kind of a file manager according to the name of the triggering user.